# Access 2007 create report from query

Tags: microsoft-access-2007, query, report

Where is my Query???  I'm using Access 2007, until this version I would create a query then create a report based in that query, using create-blank report.  If I use the report wizard it does give me the option to use the query, but when I use the wizard the report is had to edit the design.  Could someone please tell me how to create a report (from Blank Report) using my query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a control to the report go Property Sheet, Data, Control Source and choose the Query information you need. The link is to the Microsoft page on the subject I hope this helps.

> [Create-a-simple-report](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-simple-report-HA001230739.aspx)

Comment: Your comment showed me this:  I can create a Blank Report.  then open poperty sheet and pick my query.  But, now when I click Add Existing Fields, it does not show the fields from my query.  It just shows me all the tables.  So I suppose I need to pick my fields from the tables..   I think this stinks..  Why would Microsoft change this - why can't the query fields be available so I know exactally what I am puling out of my query...

Comment: I do agree, but unless you can use the wizard this is the way I have to do. I have found the wizard is a good starting place and the edit the report or form from there.

Answer (score 1):

You CAN make a blank report than add fields from a query like this:

1. Create a blank report;
2. Go to Property Sheet;
3. Choose "Data", select "Record Source" and choose your querry;
4. Save your report;
5. Open report in Design View;
6. Select "Add Existing Fields";
7. In the bottom of the Field List select option "Show only fields in the current record source";
8. Voilà.